# Ruby multi dimensional arrays and user defined function

Tags: arrays, function, global

I have many multiple dimensional arrays. A simplified example:

```
t0 = [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
t1 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
t2 = [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
t3 = [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2]
t4 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
t = [t0,t1,t2,t3,t4]
instance1= [t]
```

Each cell is processed.  For each cell the 8 ajoining cells (think terrain map) plus the equivalent cells in several other arrays are accessed and updated.  For example:

```
for h in 1..3
    for i in 1..8
        if instance1[0][i][h] == 4   # burning
            if instance1[0][i-1][h-1] > 0 && instance1[0][i-1][h-1] < 4
                # check probability
                probability =  Fernandes1(moisturex[0][i-1][h-1], windspeed, temperature, fueltypex[0][i-1][h-1])
                if probability > 0.5
                    instance2[0][i-1][h-1] = 4    # now burning
                end
            end
            if instance1[0][i-1][h] > 1 && instance1[0][i-1][h] < 4
                # check probability
             ...................................
```

I would like to perform this processing in a user defined function.  I guess the alternative to globals is to pass all variables as function parameters but that would be very tedious and error prone - there being so many.

Is the best approach to declare the arrays as global?

```
$t0 = [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
$t1 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
$t2 = [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
$t3 = [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2]
$t4 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
$t = [$t0,$t1,$t2,$t3,$t4]
$instance1= [$t]
```

And as here, do I need to define all the sub arrays as globals or just the ones that I directly reference in the user defined function?  Or by defining the outer array (i.e. $instance1) as global do the sub arrays become global?

Any guidance much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OK defining just the globals that are referenced seems to work fine (e.g. the outer array but not the sub-arrays.  I guess the only overhead of Globals is sustained use of memory.

But I'm wondering if there is a more Rubiesque way to go.